# CC3200 SPI slave issue

Tags: fpga, spi

I am trying to interface Artix-7 FPGA with CC3200MOD for SPI transfers. CC3200MOD is the slave. I am receiving only '.' on the terminal. 
SPI slave program:

```
void SlaveMain()
{
//
// Initialize the message
//
memcpy(g_ucTxBuff,SLAVE_MSG,sizeof(SLAVE_MSG));

//
// Set Tx buffer index
//
ucTxBuffNdx = 0;
ucRxBuffNdx = 0;

//
// Reset SPI
//
MAP_SPIReset(GSPI_BASE);

//Message("\n\r SPI reset");
// Configure SPI interface
//
MAP_SPIConfigSetExpClk(GSPI_BASE,MAP_PRCMPeripheralClockGet(PRCM_GSPI),
                 SPI_IF_BIT_RATE,SPI_MODE_SLAVE,SPI_SUB_MODE_3,
                 (SPI_HW_CTRL_CS |
                 SPI_4PIN_MODE |
                 SPI_TURBO_ON |
                 SPI_CS_ACTIVELOW |
                 SPI_WL_8));
Message("\n\rSPI configured");
//
// Register Interrupt Handler
//
MAP_SPIIntRegister(GSPI_BASE,SlaveIntHandler);

//
// Enable Interrupts
//
MAP_SPIIntEnable(GSPI_BASE,SPI_INT_RX_FULL|SPI_INT_TX_EMPTY);

//
// Enable SPI for communication
//
MAP_SPIEnable(GSPI_BASE);
//Message("\n\rSPI enabled");
    /*MAP_SPIReset(GSPI_BASE);

    MAP_SPIConfigSetExpClk(GSPI_BASE,MAP_PRCMPeripheralClockGet(PRCM_GSPI),
                     SPI_IF_BIT_RATE,SPI_MODE_SLAVE,SPI_SUB_MODE_0,
                     (SPI_HW_CTRL_CS |
                     SPI_4PIN_MODE |
                     SPI_TURBO_OFF |
                     SPI_CS_ACTIVELOW |
                     SPI_WL_8));

    MAP_SPIEnable(GSPI_BASE);
//}*/


}
```

The SlaveMain() function is called once in the main and then the program goes into a while(1) until SPI interrupt is hit. When SPI interrupt is hit, only '255' is received irrespective of what I transmit from the FPGA.
[image]

What can be the issue?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, I finally did it by polling. The interrupts for the LEDs worked flawlessly (sample code) but they just weren't hitting for other pins. It was kinda disappointing.